# Can you compare chars with ==?

Tags: java, char, compare, equals

For Strings you have to use equals to compare them, because == only compares the references.

Does it give the expected result if I compare chars with == ?

---

I have seen similar questions on stackoverflow, E.g.

- [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

However, I haven't seen one that asks about using == on chars.

Comment: `char`s are primitives, so **yes**.

Comment: Why don't you try this in your IDE?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not really reliable.  If this were Strings, someone might try `String a = "Hello"; String b = "Hello"; if (a == b ) { System.out.println("Equal");}` and conclude that it's OK to compare Strings with `==`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Good point, I didn't think of the String part of this.

Comment: If not using `==`, how would you do it? A `char` is not an object, so you can use `equals()` like you do for strings. If you simply tried that, you'd know immediately, because it won't compile. A little research, and a bit of logical thinking, and you'd answer your own question. Both are necessary skills if you want to program, so you should start honing those skills now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, `char` is just like any other primitive type, you can just compare them by `==`.

You can even compare char directly to numbers and use them in calculations eg:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println((int) 'a'); // cast char to int
        System.out.println('a' == 97); // char is automatically promoted to int
        System.out.println('a' + 1); // char is automatically promoted to int
        System.out.println((char) 98); // cast int to char
    }
}
```

will print:

```
97
true
98
b
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but also no.

Technically, `==` compares two `int`s. So in code like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char a = 'c';
    char b = 'd';
    if (a == b) {
        System.out.println("wtf?");
    }
}
```

Java is implicitly converting the line `a == b` into `(int) a == (int) b`.

The comparison will still "work", however.